# how to generate .exe file using pyinstaller for scrapy project?

Tags: python

Just i create desktop application using pyQt5 designer. all working fine while i am running directly using

`python main.py`
whereas i try to generate .exe file using **pyinstaller**
It's crating .exe file when I open that application it's hanging.
Can anyone resolve my issue?

`pyinstaller --onefile main.py` 
**OR**
`pyinstaller main.py`
I tried all these methods. even if can't push any error if I run main.exe in the terminal also.

```
___________main.py_________
import os
import sys
import qt5reactor
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
import twisted
from window import Ui_MainWindow
from quotes_scrapy.spiders.qscrapy import QscrapySpider


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.on_url_entered)
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.getComboValue) #Added New
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents
        )

    def crawler_results(self, item):
        row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        title = item["title"]
        author = item["author"]
        tags = item["tags"]
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(title))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(author))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(tags))

    def on_url_entered(self):
        configure_logging()
        runner = CrawlerRunner()
        runner.crawl(QscrapySpider, page_num=self.getComboValue())

        for p in runner.crawlers:
            p.signals.connect(self.crawler_results, signal=signals.item_scraped)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(MainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)
        twisted.internet.reactor.stop()

    def getComboValue(self):
        return self.comboBox.currentText()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    if 'twisted.internet.reactor' not in sys.modules:
        qt5reactor.install()
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: Try to use py2exe, Google it and follow the tutorials. It can generate exe files from py files. See if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Please post your .py file in the question body, we can't help you if we don't know what errors your script might contain.

Comment: If you are interested to solve this then let me share your mail then I can share relevant files. I think it hard to share all files here.

Comment: My email: estranger921@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

May be this doesnt help, but you can place all your imports that the top. You have one import at main(). Place it on top and try again, may be this helps.

I also made many projects using Pyqt and bundled it using pyinstaller. They worked like a charm for me.